# Android C2DM AUTHENTICATION_FAILED error while registeration

Tags: java, android

Please help me in this. I am getting authentication_failed error while registering for c2dm service. I have logged in developer account in my emulator.

```
 Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "developer@companydomain.com");
    startService(registrationIntent);
```

In the BroadcastReceiver class, I am getting authentication_failed error. Please guide me where I am wrong..

Comment: Is this "developer@companydomain.com" synched with your android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is    developer@companydomain.com the e-mail address You used for sign-up of C2DM? In this case it makes no difference what e-mail address your emulator/device has, in fact it is dicouraged to use the same e-mail both for sign-up and registration.

Just put the e-mail address you used for sign-up in the sender extra.
If you still get the error, then the problem is in your server side google account authentication(which should too be the sign-up e-mail name and password).

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Yeah.. I used the same mail address for sign up and for registration.. Is it will be the problem?

Comment: It should not be, but it is advised otherwise.

Comment: Yes you are right.. Thats the problem.. But Now I am getting SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error..

Answer (score 0):

I usually get the authentication_failed error in the server side (the one that will send C2DM messages).

Verify that server is using the correct email and password during authentication.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("Email=").append(**<EMAIL>**);
builder.append("&Passwd=").append(**<PASSWORD>**);
builder.append("&accountType=GOOGLE");
builder.append("&service=ac2dm");
```